# Simple layout with Semantic UI

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I want to make a simple layout in semantic UI i am new to it, i struggled to make thing work correctly attached is the design :
[image]

what you see is the mobile layout. Requirement : The header is fixed, the sidebar is fixed when we scroll through the blog content. We have a simple inverted L shaped, the only moving part is the content.

What is the minimum code to do this in a clean way?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: sorry what is the minimum code to do this in a clean way?

Comment: Please edit your post, and ask a clear question: How, what, why?

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

After a few tweak i managed to get this layout

here is the CSS code :

`

```
/* custom css by me*/
.lateral {
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-left: -1em;
  margin-right: -1em;
  color: #fff; }

.lateral-item {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  padding-left: 14px !important; }

.menu-item {
  padding-top: 15px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important; }

.text-container {
  margin-top: 90px !important; }

.lateral-sidebar {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #00A42F;
  padding-right: 0px !important; }

.custom-green {
  background-color: #00A42F !important; }

/* pointer */
.ui.vertical.pointing.menu .item:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  margin: 0em -0.5px 0em 0em;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff; }

.ui.inverted.menu .item:before {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0; }
```

`

And the HTML Code

`

```
    <div class="ui menu inverted custom-green" style="width: 100%;border:none">

            <div class="item custom-green" style="width: 100px;" >
                <img class="ui mini image circular centered" src="photo.jpg" />
            </div>


        <div  style="width:100%">
            <div>
                <div class="ui menu custom-green" style="border: none;box-shadow:none">

                    <span href="#" class="item">Name</span>
                    <div class="right menu" style="border: none;box-shadow:none">
                        <a href="#" class="right item">Disconnect</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div>
                <div class="ui menu custom-green" style="border:none;">
                    <span style="border:none" href="#" class="item">Page Title</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

this is done with Semantic UI, i am not sure if the code is minimal but i needed to override the original css rules.